# No module named 'sklearn.svm._classes' when loading model from colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, joblib

I've trained a model on google colab and want to load it on my local machine. But I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.svm._classes'`. Loading the model on colab, is no problem.

colab:

```
[1] import sys
    sys.version
'3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) \n[GCC 8.3.0]'
[2] import joblib
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn import svm
    clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)
    clf.fit(np.random.rand(9,8).astype(int), np.arange(9))
    joblib.dump(clf, 'simple_classifier')
[3] joblib.load('simple_classifier')
```

My local machine:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) \n[GCC 8.3.0]'
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import joblib
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> joblib.load('simple_classifier')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/.../ml-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 605, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/home/.../ml-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 529, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 1050, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 1338, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 1388, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.svm._classes'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Serialization via `joblib` will only work if the versions of installed packages correspond **exactly** between the program saving the model and the program loading it.

From the error you are seeing, I suspect that you are using different versions of `scikit-learn` on Co-Lab and your local machine. Make sure versions of relevant packages match, and you should be able to load the model.

See https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade the sklearn library using:

```
pip install scikit-learn --upgrade
```

Occurs when the model was built with a specific version of the library and tested with other versions.

Comment: Yes! Had the same error with sklearn.tree
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.tree.tree'"

Solution was to upgrade sklearn for both servers using these files!